# hubot rocketchat broadcast notification

Tags: node.js, sdk, chatbot, hubot, rocket.chat

I'm trying to send broadcast notification in direct message via bot ([bot repository](https://github.com/RocketChat/hubot-rocketchat-boilerplate)):

```js
const { driver } = require('@rocket.chat/sdk');
    
module.exports = (robot) => {
    robot.respond(/notify/i, (msg) => {
         let userNames = ['1','2','3'];
         userNames.forEach(userName => driver.sendDirectToUser(message, userName));
    }
}
```

In the administration panel of Rocket.Chat server I turned off all rate limiters, but every time I get an exception :

```js
ERROR [createDirectMessage] Error: {
isClientSafe: true,
error: 'too-many-requests',
reason: 'Error, too many requests. Please slow down. You must wait 54 seconds before trying again.',
details: { timeToReset: 53009 },
message: 'Error, too many requests. Please slow down. You must wait 54 seconds before trying again. [too-many-requests]',
errorType: 'Meteor.Error'
}
```

I've also tried to change limit values, but looks like it did't help.
I have about 2000 users and at some point it throws an exception.

**UPD**

As for now I had to use code like this:

```
function sendMessages(userNames, message, timeOut = 120 /*ms*/) {
        let step = timeOut;
        userNames.forEach(userName => sendWait(() => driver.sendDirectToUser(message, userName).catch(error => {}), timeOut+=step))
    }

    function sendWait(action, milliseconds) {
        if (typeof(action) != 'function')
            return;
        setTimeout(action, milliseconds);
    }
```